# Python: How to read from file of numbers (scores) use as list and get high score, low, and average score, and group into deciles

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, readfile

Ok, I need help with this problem and its my last project of college and I am not a csc major so I really just need some help!! I need to read from a file of random numbers and find the max, min and avg. And then group how many scores are in each (10%) decile from 0-100. Not sure why my code isn't running, I have only attempted getting the min, max and average so far.

I have looked for help with the reading file to list issue but a lot of the solutions include some type of "with" loop thing, which I haven't learned yet. Also, was thinking of maybe having separate functions/methods for the sorting and then the percentage/stars. Thank you for any help!

Example output:

The high score is: 100

The low score is: 0

The average is: 55.49

Range    Number    Percent

=========================================

0-9         75          7.5%  *******

10-19       82          8.2%  ********

etc....

Input file is a .txt file with each score on a new line.

> 33 
>   99 
>   14 
>   52
>   76
>   78

```
This is the error that comes out:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meganhorton/Desktop/Python/hw5.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/meganhorton/Desktop/Python/hw5.py", line 20, in main
    avgScore = float(sum(scoresList)/len(scoresList))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

Comment: Upon glancing at the code, it looks like the `for` loop is off. You iterate with `for line in scoresList` but you never do anything with `line` inside.

Comment: can you add example of your input file. So far it looks that you just need to convert strings (lines) that you read from file into numbers. but need to see example of a input file

Comment: To get good answers in stack overflow you need to ask the right questions rather than generally say "I just need some help".  Try asking "why does my code not run?". Make sure you post the output of your program and any information needed for helpers to run it (like the oldscores.txt file). Having said that, @Mangohero1 is right. You have a foreach loop creating a variable 'line' that you do not use in the loop. Instead you are calling max() and min(), and calculating the average multiple times. However that should not stop the program working, just slow it down massively. Post actual output.

Comment: Assuming the file is just numbers each on its own line, Python cannot run `sum()` on strings. You'd need to cast each number in the list as an integer. You can do this by doing a list comprehension like this: `scoresList = [int(s) for s in scoresList]`

Comment: Mangohero1 thank you for your most recent comment!! I added that and got the correct min, max and avg!! Unfortunately its now saying "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close'" after it calculates those. I also added an example of the file input!

Comment: Dmitry Tokarev thank you! I added an example of the input file as well

Comment: @Felix thank you! I posted some example output.. However I adjusted it and added Mangohero1's most recent addition and it now says "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close" and does the min, max and avg calcs

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of solving your problem using pure Python:

```
with open("scores.txt", "r") as inFile:
    scores = [int(line) for line in inFile]
    maximum = max(scores)
    minimum = min(scores)
    average = sum(scores) / len(scores)

    deciles = [0 for i in range(10)]
    for score in scores:
        for i in range(0,100,10):
            if score in range(i, i+10):
                deciles[int(i/10)] += 1

    print("The high score is: %d" % maximum)
    print("The low score is: %d" % minimum)
    print("The average is: %.2f" % average)

    print("=========================================")

    for i in range(10):
        print("%d - %d" % (i*10, i*10+9), end=" ")
        print(deciles[i], end=" ")
        print("%.2f %s" % (((deciles[i] / sum(deciles)) * 100.0), "%"), end=" ")
        print("*" * deciles[i])
```

Output of the example data you provided:

```
The high score is: 98
The low score is: 18
The average is: 66.83
=========================================
0 - 9 0 0.00 % 
10 - 19 1 16.67 % *
20 - 29 0 0.00 % 
30 - 39 0 0.00 % 
40 - 49 1 16.67 % *
50 - 59 1 16.67 % *
60 - 69 0 0.00 % 
70 - 79 0 0.00 % 
80 - 89 0 0.00 % 
90 - 99 3 50.00 % ***
```

Comment: Meg, I would appreciate your upvote or accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There are handy dandy tools for data crunching in python.  I recommend `pandas`, as it can do a lot of this with a single function calls.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("OldScores.txt", header=None, names=["scores"])
high_score = df["scores"].max()
low_score = df["scores"].min()
mean_score = df["scores"].mean()
median_score = df["scores"].median()
counts, divisions = np.histogram(df["scores"], bins=list(range(0,101,10)))
relative_counts = counts/df["scores"].shape[0]
```

Comment: Also of note, is that it's considered poor form, in python, to catch an exception only to print that exception.  Best to just let it go.

Comment: Scott thank you, I really appreciate it and while pandas is probably way more efficient, this is for a class assignment and I haven't learned any of it so I won't be able to use it:( I have to stick with using lists, loops and whatnot bc thats all I know